# ManyToMany relation deletes rows

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many

I got very weird situation.
I got class A and B and relation ManyToMany like this:

A.class:

```
@ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="a_b",
            joinColumns={
                @JoinColumn(name="a_id")
        }, inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="b_id")
    }
    )
private List<B> blist;
```

B.class:

```
@ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(name="a_b",
                joinColumns={
                    @JoinColumn(name="b_id")
            }, inverseJoinColumns={
                @JoinColumn(name="a_id")
        }
        )
    private List<A> alist;
```

when I update instance of A class, Hibernate deletes all relation ('delete from a_b where a_id=?)
In my database i got no cascade type rules.
What could be the reason of that situation?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that you are using Save and not SaveOrUpdate. Is that the case ? The class annotations seems fine, there is something else that is causing the problem. Could you post more information?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you do not specify the cascade type. The default is `CascadeType.None` so as a result the update that the parent ID has changed doesn't get propagated to the children so Hibernate will delete the orphans. I believe so you'll need to specify the following in your attribute:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)    //Use whatever CascadeType fits your need
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following mapping

**A.class**

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = B.class)
@JoinTable(name = "a_b",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "a_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "b_id"))
private List<B> blist;
```

**B.class**

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "blist", targetEntity = A.class)
private List<A> alist;
```